# Construction of conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\epsilon>0$. I was asked to find a conformal mapping from

$(\mathbb{R}\times(0,2))-((-\infty,i-\epsilon ] \cup[i+\epsilon,i+\infty))$

(An infinite horizontal strip but chopped a fine strip symmetrically)

to $\mathbb{H}$, the upper half plane.

The main obstacle is that I do not know how to deal with the chopped part. Does inversion help? But this is just a bounded strip instead of a "unbouneded" strip.

Comment: What do you mean by $$(-\infty,i-\epsilon ] \cup[i+\epsilon,i+\infty)\ ?$$

Comment: Sorry. this is an abuse of notation.
For example, $(\infty,i-\epsilon]$ means the horizontal line extends from $i-\epsilon$ to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Start with $z \to w = e^{z \pi}$, mapping your region to ${\mathbb C}$ with two rays removed.  Next, invert around an endpoint of one of those rays.

Comment: Isn't the image of $e^{\pi z}$ equal to $\mathbb{C}$ with one ray and one line segment removed?

Comment: The real line and $\text{Im}\ z = 2$ go to the positive real axis;
the ray from $i-\infty$ to $i - \epsilon$ to the line segment from $0$ to $-e^{-\pi \epsilon}$; the ray from $i+\epsilon$ to $i+\infty$ to the ray from $-e^{+\pi \epsilon}$ to $-\infty$.  And of course $0$ is not in the image either.